# read data through stream sets from a continuously updating file

Tags: file, server, streamsets

I want to read data from an active file through stream sets. when I tried running pipeline using file tail origin after updating the existing file, it is displaying the below error:

> message:Pipeline Status: RUNNING_ERROR:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: LiveFileReader for
>   'LiveFile[path=/home/spandanad/something/test1.log.2018-10-03,
>   iNode=(dev=fd02,ino=5433), headHash=Hm0Vsfo8J8zr8Co+p9sAFA==]' is not
>   open

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace (including any 'Caused By' sections) from sdc.log?